# Need to prove $(JC=0=CJ,\,JJ=nJ)\implies (C-aJ)^{-1}-(C-bJ)^{-1}=\frac{b-a}{ab n^2} J$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I can't prove that

> matrix $C$: $$\big(JC = 0 = CJ\text{ and } JJ = nJ\big)
> \implies \left((C-aJ)^{-1} - (C-bJ)^{-1} = \frac{b-a}{abn^2} J\right)$$

I know that
$$(JC = 0 = CJ\text{ and }JJ = nJ)
\implies \left((C-aJ)J = J(C-aJ) = \frac 1{an}J\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. The correct assertion should be
$$
(C-aJ)^{-1} - (C-bJ)^{-1} = \frac{\color{red}{a-b}}{abn^2} J.
$$
To verify it, just multiply both sides by $(C-aJ)(C-bJ)$ and expand.